Escaping sign in spring cloud config server
I have spring cloud config server which provides password to rabbit. Password contains "@". When I run app with static appliation.yaml i have to surround value with ''
spring:
  rabbitmq:
  addresses: localhost:5672
  username: guest
  password: '@xxx'

but when i get it from config server, with jdbc storage, password didn't match. I've tried many ways to escape '@' but without success.

Try to escape the @ with one of the following options
using backslash
password: mypass\\@secure

or with encoding %40
password: mypass%40secure

